# SSD Software-Raid-0 Ubuntu not as fast as expected

Tags: software-raid, ssd, pci-express

I have an MB ASRock B650 Phantom with two SSD 1TB Samsung 990 PRO m.2 PCIe 4 drives. I set them up in a software Raid-0 with lukscrypt on Ubuntu. The SSD should reach 7.450 MB/s reading, in my naivety I expected almost twice the speed in a RAID-0, but a benchmark shows a maximum of 7200 MB/s.

What am I missing? Is there an other limiting factor? Can I improve the speed somehow?

[image]